# How to debug backend written in Node.js with TypeScript in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, debugging, typescript, webstorm

I am writing backend for an application in Node.js with Typescript. I am using WebStorm IDE version 11.0.4.

Is there any way to debug code where I can directly add breakpoints in TypeScript not in transpiled JavaScript ?

Comment: This should just work if you have sourcemaps properly generated; if it doesn't work, please create a support ticket

Comment: @lena Setup instructions would be helpful

Comment: No special instructions - just make sure to generate sourcemaps, create a node.js run configuration for the generated main js file and start debugging

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in your tsconfig.json file, inside the compilerOptions there is:

```
"sourceMap": true
```